# SQL: How to query the distinct values for all columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

For example,
The table has 3 rows and 3 columns:

**Name Age Gender**

Peter 25 M 

John 29 M 

Alex 25 M

And I want to query the table and get

**Name  Age Gender**

Peter 25 M

John  29

Alex

The method I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name,Age,Gender FROM table
```

The output is still

**Name Age Gender**

Peter 25 M 

John 29 M 

Alex 25 M

How to achieve the table that there is no redundant entries for every field? Thanks.

Thanks for the help from all of you, especially the help from donPablo.
Here's my VBA code to achieve that. Since I am totally new to VBA, the code might not be very clean and efficient. But at least it works.

```
Option Compare Database

Sub ReadDistinctValue()

Dim d As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim FN As Field, Age As Field, Sex As Field

Set d = CurrentDb()
Set rs = d.OpenRecordset("Table1")
Set FN = rs.Fields("FN")
Set Age = rs.Fields("Age")
Set Sex = rs.Fields("Sex")

d.Execute "CREATE TABLE Table4 (FN Text,Age Text,Sex Text)"

While Not rs.EOF
    If CheckFN(FN) = False Then
        Call WriteFN(FN)
    End If
    If CheckAge(Age) = False Then
        Call WriteAge(Age)
    End If
    If CheckSex(Sex) = False Then
        Call WriteSex(Sex)
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

rs.Close

End Sub

Function CheckFN(FN As Field) As Boolean

Dim d As Database
Dim rs_new As Recordset
Dim FN_new As Field

Set d = CurrentDb()
Set rs_new = d.OpenRecordset("Table4")
Set FN_new = rs_new.Fields("FN")

CheckFN = False

Do While Not rs_new.EOF
    If FN_new = FN Then
        CheckFN = True
        Exit Do
    End If
    rs_new.MoveNext
Loop

rs_new.Close

End Function

Function WriteFN(FN As Field)
Dim d As Database
Dim rs_new As Recordset
Dim FN_new As Field

Set d = CurrentDb()
Set rs_new = d.OpenRecordset("Table4")
Set FN_new = rs_new.Fields("FN")

If Not rs_new.EOF Then
    rs_new.MoveFirst
End If

Do While True
    If rs_new.EOF Then
        rs_new.AddNew
        FN_new = FN
        rs_new.Update
        Exit Do
    End If
    If IsNull(FN_new.Value) Then
        rs_new.Edit
        FN_new = FN
        rs_new.Update
        Exit Do
    End If
    rs_new.MoveNext
Loop
rs_new.Close
End Function

Function CheckAge(Age As Field) As Boolean

Dim d As Database
Dim rs_new As Recordset
Dim Age_new As Field

Set d = CurrentDb()
Set rs_new = d.OpenRecordset("Table4")
Set Age_new = rs_new.Fields("Age")

CheckAge = False

Do While Not rs_new.EOF
    If Age_new = Age Then
        CheckAge = True
        Exit Do
    End If
    rs_new.MoveNext
Loop

rs_new.Close

End Function

Function WriteAge(Age As Field)
Dim d As Database
Dim rs_new As Recordset
Dim Age_new As Field

Set d = CurrentDb()
Set rs_new = d.OpenRecordset("Table4")
Set Age_new = rs_new.Fields("Age")

If Not rs_new.EOF Then
    rs_new.MoveFirst
End If

Do While True
    If rs_new.EOF Then
        rs_new.AddNew
        Age_new = Age
        rs_new.Update
        Exit Do
    End If
    If IsNull(Age_new.Value) Then
        rs_new.Edit
        Age_new = Age
        rs_new.Update
        Exit Do
    End If
    rs_new.MoveNext
Loop
rs_new.Close
End Function

Function CheckSex(Sex As Field) As Boolean

Dim d As Database
Dim rs_new As Recordset
Dim Sex_new As Field

Set d = CurrentDb()
Set rs_new = d.OpenRecordset("Table4")
Set Sex_new = rs_new.Fields("Sex")

CheckSex = False

Do While Not rs_new.EOF
    If Sex_new = Sex Then
        CheckSex = True
        Exit Do
    End If
    rs_new.MoveNext
Loop

rs_new.Close

End Function

Function WriteSex(Sex As Field)
Dim d As Database
Dim rs_new As Recordset
Dim Sex_new As Field

Set d = CurrentDb()
Set rs_new = d.OpenRecordset("Table4")
Set Sex_new = rs_new.Fields("Sex")

If Not rs_new.EOF Then
    rs_new.MoveFirst
End If

Do While True
    If rs_new.EOF Then
        rs_new.AddNew
        Sex_new = Sex
        rs_new.Update
        Exit Do
    End If
    If IsNull(Sex_new.Value) Then
        rs_new.Edit
        Sex_new = Sex
        rs_new.Update
        Exit Do
    End If
    rs_new.MoveNext
Loop
rs_new.Close
End Function
```

Comment: Does the result need to be formatted like that?

Comment: No, the result just needs to be a table

Comment: have you tried using SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName FROM Table?

Comment: You mean SELECT DISTINCT (Name,Age,Gender) FROM Table

Comment: Yes. This site will work best for you if you can provide things you have tried so we can see what you are asking for. Questions that are formed as a HowTo don't generally get a good response, if any.

Comment: It does not work, the output will be the same as the original file. The SELECT DISCINCT command will output the whole row as long as one field is different.

Comment: Please edit the question to include what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

By naming the three columns, you are retrieving distinct combinations of that set of values.

If you want lists of distinct values, name each individually in a select.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table

SELECT DISTINCT Age FROM table

SELECT DISTINCT Gender FROM table
```

If you are trying to get them to display as you have in your example, that will have to be accomplished by some GUI functionality. SQL database engines are not good at display trickery, just handling data.

Answer (score 0):

I have expanded the table values a little, just to see what would happen --

```
FN      Age Sex
Alice   28  F
Ben     19  M
Charles 33  M
Doug    23  M
Elaine  21  F
Frank   25  M
Gwen    28  F
Helen   33  F
Alice   17  F
Ben     21  F
```

Then I developed a single query for FN, and later generalized to all three fields --

The clue is to sequence # each FN/AGE/SEX and then join on that seq#--

```
SELECT 
   AB.fn,
   CD.age,
   EF.sex

FROM   
((SELECT A.fn, Count(B.fn) AS CNTfn
    FROM   
    (SELECT DISTINCT fn FROM   table1) AS A,
    (SELECT DISTINCT fn FROM   table1) AS B
    WHERE  B.fn <= A.fn
    GROUP  BY A.fn) AS AB

LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT C.age, Count(D.age) AS CNTage
    FROM   
    (SELECT DISTINCT age FROM   table1) AS C,
    (SELECT DISTINCT age FROM   table1) AS D
    WHERE  D.age <= C.age
    GROUP  BY C.age) AS CD
ON AB.cntfn = CD.cntage)

LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT E.sex, Count(F.sex) AS CNTsex
    FROM   
    (SELECT DISTINCT sex FROM   table1) AS E,
    (SELECT DISTINCT sex FROM   table1) AS F
    WHERE  F.sex <= E.sex
    GROUP  BY E.sex) AS EF
ON AB.cntfn = EF.CNTsex;
```

This gives the results desired --

```
FN  AGE SEX
Alice   17  F
Ben     19  M
Charles 21  
Doug    23  
Elaine  25  
Frank   28  
Gwen    33  
Helen
```

I changed the Sex in my sample table, and added to the following as the first sequencing of the un-Distinct whole table and changed the ON... to XZ.cntall ...

```
(SELECT X.FN & X.AGE & X.SEX, Count(*) AS CNTall
FROM   
(SELECT DISTINCT FN, AGE,  SEX FROM   table1) AS X,
(SELECT DISTINCT FN, AGE,  SEX FROM   table1) AS Z
WHERE  Z.FN & Z.AGE & Z.SEX <= X.FN & X.AGE & X.SEX
GROUP  BY X.FN,  X.AGE,  X.SEX) as XZ
```

and now get these results

```
fn     age  sex
Alice   17  M
Ben     19  N
Charles 21  O
Doug    23  P
Elaine  25  Q
Frank   28  R
Gwen    33  W
Helen       X
            Y
            Z
```

Comment: Thanks. It is very helpful. However, there is one constraint for the method. The number of distinct values in each column has to be decreasing along with the increasing of the column number due to the feature of LEFT JOIN. Is there any method to get rid of the constraint? I am working on Access 2013.

Comment: I tried to use UNION to get rid of the constrain, but it becomes very complicated to find out which part should be added and which part should be deleted to achieve the same effect of FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: Just a thought -- before the FN sequencing, add code to sequence the entire un-Distinct table, and then Left-join everything to that.

Answer (score -2):

There is probably an SQL solution for this.  I am constantly amazed at what can be done.  However, my answer is that this is a perfect application for VBA.

Comment: Can you elaborate on a possible SQL solution, or how this could be accomplished specifically in VBA? You are probably getting downvotes because there isnt enough explanation of either in this answer.

Comment: I will use VBA to solve it instead. I just wanted to figure out whether there was a simple solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry I won't help more with the VBA, but I think a bit more information would be needed before launching into it.